# install HDF5 and pytables in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, hdf5, pytables

I am trying to install `tables` package in Ubuntu 14.04 but sems like it is complaining.

I am trying to install it using PyCharm and its package installer, however seems like it is complaining about `HDF5` package.

However, seems like I cannnot find any `hdf5` package to install before `tables`.

Could anyone explain the procedure to follow?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to install libhdf5-7 and python-tables via apt

Comment: Apt couldn't find the `libhdf5-7` package on Ubunu 18.04. T.C.'s answer below worked for me though.

Answer (score 70):

I found that installing the `libhdf5-serial-dev` with

```
  sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev
```

did the trick.

Comment: This works on a more bare-bones system. It should be the top answer.

Comment: You might also need to install `python-dev`, `python3-dev`, or `python3.X-dev` depending on which version of Python you're running (if this hasn't already been done, which on a new system it isn't usually).

Answer (score 15):

Search for the HDF5 library in the ubuntu package repository.

```
apt-cache search hdf5
```

The command will show the packages relating to hdf5.

install the relevant package to you.

```
sudo apt-get install package-name.
```

mostly you have to install the hdf5-tools, h5utils, python-tables.

Answer (score 10):

To be more precise, do two steps on Ubuntu

1) install hdf5

```
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev
```

2) install pytables

```
pip install tables
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks for saving time and energy